# Is there any way to save the plugins settings in WordPress.

Tags: wordpress

First of all I'm new to WordPress. I'm using some plugins on my wordpress site (ex: Google map plugin is configured with my google map api). I would like to save the plugin's setting and download it for future usage. In case if the wordpress installation has been re-installed, then i have to use the google map plugin(which is already configured with api) without configuring it again. Please advise.

Comment: Check the plugin options. If it allows you to save and import your changes then you can import the setting/changes for future use.

Comment: @Sharif MoMohammad Eunus, thanks for the reply. Most of the plugins doesn't have the features to save the settings and download it. I'm using an auto post generator plugin, which requires a couple of dozen checkboxes to check for the settings. For testing purposes, i need to remove the wordpress installation and have to re-install it. While doing this, corresponding plugins are needs to be re-configure from the beginning. Any ideas to overcome this situation?

Comment: Sorry for the typos.

Comment: are you doing this on your local machine?

Comment: If you are just playing around then you can delete/disable the plugin deactivation hook which is responsible for deleting data while plugin deactivation.

Comment: Another way is you can use macro to prevent yourself doing the same work. There are some extension for both chrome and firefox. just search for `imacros`. It might make your life a bit easier.